# How can we set the value to the header dynamically in SOAPUi?

Tags: xpath, soapui

I'm new to SoapUI. I wanted to know how can we add 2 property value into one Header value.

For instance, I got some response like in XML format:

```
<Response xmlns="Http://SomeUrl">
    <access_token>abc</access_token>
    <scope>scope1</scope>
    <token_type>Bearer</token_type>
</Response>
```

I want to send both access_token & token type to a single header value like:

```
"Authorization":"Bearer abc"
```

I am not getting how to do this using property transfer step.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/concat) function to concatenate the both values in one variable in your property transfer steps, in your case you can use the follow XPath:

```
concat(//*:token_type," ",//*:access_token)
```

concat function concatenates two or more strings, `//*:token_type` gets the `Bearer` value and `//*:access_token` gets the `abc`.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Add a script step after the step returning what you describe above.

```
def tokenType = context.expand('${STEP RETURNING STUFF#Response#//Response/token_type}');
def token = context.expand('${STEP RETURNING STUFF#Response#//Response/access_token}');

//add header to all steps
for (def stepEntry : testRunner.testCase.testSteps) {
    if (!(stepEntry.value instanceof com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlTestRequestStep)) {
        continue;
    }
    def headers = stepEntry.value.httpRequest.requestHeaders;

    headers.remove("Authorization");
    headers.put("Authorization", token_type + " " + token); 
    stepEntry.value.httpRequest.requestHeaders = headers;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way without using additional property transfer step, but uses script assertion

1. Add a script assertion for the request test step.
2. Use below code into that script, modify element XPath are required

```
def element1Xpath = '//*:token_type'
def element2Xpath = '//*:access_token'
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def response = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(messageExchange.responseContentAsXml)
def field1 = response.getNodeValue(element1Xpath)
def field2 = response.getNodeValue(element2Xpath)
if (!field1) { throw new Error ("${element1Xpath} is either empty or null")  }
if (!field1) { throw new Error ("${element2Xpath} is either empty or null")  }
context.testCase.setPropertyValue('TEMP_PROPERTY', "${field1} ${field2}")
```

3. Now the expected value(merged) is available in a property 'TEMP_PROPERTY'. You may rename the property name as you wish in the last line of the code.
4. You may the new wherever it is needed within the test case.